# Object always nothing when invoking System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reflection

Basically, in this code x is always nothing....

```
dim x as new object
x = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("MyCode.MyClass")
```

In effect, what I'm really trying to do, in the end is this... (setting x as an instance of class MyCode.MyClass)...

```
dim x as new MyCode.MyClass
```

Do you know what the issue with the first set of code could be?

I know what you may be thinking. "Why not just do it the second way?" Yes, that would be easier. But, now a little background: We have pretty complicated business rules, customer requirements, etc... in our asp.net web app. But, basically, in one of our database tables there is a field which defines the current datatype/class of a variable. This field is a string. So, using this string, and given the various business rules, I need to ***dynamically*** define/instantiate my variable x as a certain class. In the above example "MyCode.MyClass" is the string in the field. So, the x object needs to be an instance of this class. Sometimes x will be an instance of "MyCode.MyClass", other times an instance of "MyCode.AnotherClass", etc....

Is there a better solution than what I'm coding above?

I also tried this, which produced errors...

```
Dim x As Object = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "MyCode.MyClass").Unwrap()
```

Sorry it's so complex.

***Update 1***: I'm getting closer. When I try this code both o and x print out the same and look correct.

```
        o = System.Activator.CreateInstance("MyCode", "MyCode.MyClass").Unwrap
        Debug.Print(o.GetType.FullName)

        Dim x As New MyCode.MyClass
        Debug.Print(x.GetType.FullName)
```

But, when I do a x followed by "." (to get intellisense) what appears is different than o followed by "." Any ideas why? When I do this the properties seem the same...

```
        ' print out properties for each object
        Dim info() As PropertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperties()
        Debug.Print(info.Length.ToString)

        Dim info2() As PropertyInfo = x.GetType().GetProperties()
        Debug.Print(info2.Length.ToString)
```

I think it might be because in this example o is binding late. Option strict is currently on. Am I correct in thinking this? If so, anyway around this?

Comment: In order for that to work, the assembly (dll) in which the class you are trying to instantiate resides, that dll has to be discovered at runtime (ideally in the same bin directory), is that true in your case?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same directory. I updated my text above with 2 more things I tried. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try providing explicitly the the type in the full format as shown here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx

Comment: What exceptions did the Activator.CreateInstance call throw?

Comment: @MikeHofer - "System.ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.  Parameter name: typeName@0     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)...."

Comment: Actually "MyClass" is defined in a referenced DLL. So maybe I need to reference another assembly?

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 - The exception message is fairly clear: the type name is invalid. You must *fully qualify* the type name. Include the full namespace in the type if it isn't there.

Comment: @MikeHofer Please see "Update 1" above. I think I'm getting closer here.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 - Try writing their type names to the debugger (`Debugger.WriteLine(o.GetType().FullName` and `Debugger.WriteLine(x.GetType().FullName`) to verify that they are, in fact the same type.